# Submit to Google Form using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, forms, posting

I know this question was asked before. And my code is basically utilizing that and some other post here. However I am receiving an error where the page is not found in the response data.

```
-(void)sendToForm{
whereString = whereField.text;
nameString=name.text;
phoneString=phone.text;
emailString=email.text;
dateChoice = dateLabel.text;
serviceChoice = whatLabel.text;
//initialize new mutable data ***I DONT SEE WHAT THE POINT OF THIS IS
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
//THIS GIVES me an error, received data is not defined anywhere
//    self.receivedData = data; 

//initialize url that is going to be fetched.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1jeyxQYlgIUylhXnZZEcy6BC2dx_2AUB3qSNuCqFHUDU/viewform"];

//initialize a request from url
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

//set http method
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//initialize a post data
NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"entry.1550955212=%@&entry.935955213=%@&entry.1547576233=%@&entry.202631922=%@&entry.1387567225=%@&entry.1031369018",serviceChoice,dateChoice,whereString,emailString,phoneString,nameString];    //set request content type we MUST set this value.
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//set post data of request
[request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//initialize a connection from request
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

//start the connection
[connection start];
}
```

I have some functions checking the connection and response and they all work. but in the response data it returns as Page Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Needed to be formResponse instead of viewForm